# Expected view to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk"

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I'm writing a test for a Django Rest Framework view following closely the [testing documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/)

Here's my simple test:

```
def test_patient_detail_api_opens(self):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    view =PatientDetailApi.as_view()
    request = factory.get(reverse('api_pacjent', kwargs={'pk' :1}))
    force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
    response = view(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

This test fails with the following message:

```
AssertionError: Expected view PatientDetailApi to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

I fail to understand why this is happening and how to fix this.

- The `pk` kwargs is there in the URL,
- according to the docs there's no need to add the `lookup-field` value explicitly if it defaults to `pk`,
- the view opens correctly and yet this test fails...

**Can somebody please explain why this error occurs?**

Here's the relevant code:

the 'main' `url.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^pacjent/', include('pacjent.urls')),
]
```

`pacjent.urls` looks like this:

```
url(r'^api/szczegoly/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PatientDetailApi.as_view(), name="api_pacjent"),
```

And `PatientDetailApi` is this:

```
class PatientDetailApi(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    model = Patient
    serializer_class = PatientDetailsSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()

    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Comment: Does it work when you actually request the api outside of your test, eg via Postman? Or if you use the APIClient?

Comment: It does. It was the missing part mentioned by RemcoGerlich. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @user1544500 what will be the API endpoint if you call your API from postman with named argument?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

View functions are called with the request and the arguments from the URL. So pass them:

```
response = view(request, pk=1)
```

Comment: OMG, I tried to add it to the `as_view` and then the `factory.get`, then trying to fiddle with the request itself...

Answer (score 8):

I encountered similar error when I made a mistake of using get_object method in perform_create. Read why this wrong from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object)

```
perform_create(self,instance):
      instance = self.get_object()
```